# Scroll grafica js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Necesito que cuando se de clic ya sea en el icono de flecha derecha o izquierda la gráfica se mueva al lado correspondiente como lo hace con el scroll de la parte inferior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7xWe.png)

Este es el codigo:

https://jsfiddle.net/ztxch2nd/16/

Les agradezco su ayuda e ideas para hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar este código JS

```
var scrollBack = document.getElementById('back');
var scrollNext = document.getElementById('next');

scrollBack.onclick = function () {
    scroll('left', 20);
};

scrollNext.onclick = function () {
    scroll('right', 20);
};

function scroll(direction,step){
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    amount = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(direction == 'left'){
            container.scrollLeft -= step;
        } else {
            container.scrollLeft += step;
        }
        amount += step;
        if(amount >= 100){
            window.clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Luego:
Agregarle el id 'back' a la flecha izquierda
Agregarle el id 'container' al div "draggable"
Agregarle el id 'next' a la flecha derecha

Aca dejo el código: https://jsfiddle.net/bk8c5eg0/